# Изменение количество grid

Tags: css

По задумке должно быть 2 grid
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В мобильной версии должна быть 1 grid.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменять количество grid медиа запросами ?  Если использовать этот код.
Из за разных ширин, grid делает разные отступы. Выглядит примерно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
    minmax(auto, 1fr)  /* 1 колонка */
    minmax(auto, 1fr); /* 2 колонка */
  width: fit-content; /* ширина всего грида */  
  background: #212a5f;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper div {
  padding: 5px; /* отступы от краев */
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: bold; /* первая колонка жирнее */
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">

<div class="wrapper">
   <div>Звание</div>
   <div>Мин. командир</div>
   <div>Рейтинг (ММР)</div>
   <div>3000ММР</div>
   <div>Роль</div>
   <div>Актив</div>
   <div>Звание</div>
   <div>Солдат</div>
   <div>Статус</div>
   <div>Prime</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div>Позиция</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>Класс героя</div>
   <div>Хил</div>
   <div>Часов в игре</div>
   <div>567 часов</div>
   <div>Режим игры</div>
   <div>Аркада</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как-то не похоже, что на мобильной версии должен быть один грид. Видно же, что второй стобик не там, где у первогого грида.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
    minmax(auto, 1fr)  /* 1 колонка */
    minmax(auto, 1fr); /* 2 колонка */
  width: fit-content; /* ширина всего грида */  
  background: #212a5f;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper div {
  padding: 5px; /* отступы от краев */
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(odd) {
  font-weight: bold; /* первая колонка жирнее */
}

.container
{
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 677px)
{
  .container
  {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .wrapper
  {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div>Звание</div>
     <div>Мин. командир</div>
     <div>Рейтинг (ММР)</div>
     <div>3000ММР</div>
     <div>Роль</div>
     <div>Актив</div>
     <div>Звание</div>
     <div>Солдат</div>
     <div>Статус</div>
     <div>Prime</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div>Позиция</div>
     <div>6</div>
     <div>Класс героя</div>
     <div>Хил</div>
     <div>Часов в игре</div>
     <div>567 часов</div>
     <div>Режим игры</div>
     <div>Аркада</div>
  </div>
</div>
```